Sufficient condition of local extremum
I have a function: $z=x³+y²$ and I need to find local extremum of  it.
I used necessary condition of local extremum: $\frac{∂z}{∂x}=0$ and $\frac{∂z}{∂y}$:
$\frac{∂z}{∂x}=3x²=0 ; \frac{∂z}{∂y}=2y=0$ hence $x=y=0$ and critical point is $(0,0)$
Then I used sufficient condition of local extremum: if $d²z>0$ and $dz=0$ in some point then this point is a point of local minimum:
$d²z=6xdx²+2dy²=\{x=0\}=2dy²>0$ hence $(0,0)$ is a point of local minimum of $z$.
However if we fix $y=0$ and change value $x$ $(x,0)$ then we can see that if $x<0$ then $(x,y)<(0,0)$ and if $x>0$ then $(x,y)>(0,0)$ for a sufficiently small value $x$. Consequently $(0,0)$ is not a point of local minimum. I don`t understand where I made a mistake in my reasoning.

For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, e.g., here, here, here and here.

Your mistake is in claiming that "2dy²" (which I prefer to write $\begin{pmatrix}0&0\0&2\end{pmatrix}$) is > 0. It is only $\ge0$.
